# How can i access this p tag content in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, jsx

I have this obj, I want to access this p tag content and render it through props. Without dangrouslySetInnerHTML method. What should I've to do?

```
let content = {
    para: `<p>A listing page is the public view of a listing. It should informations be designed to display all relevant information about a listing.</p>`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the text via [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), then use usual JSX to render that text in a JSX paragraph.

```js
const { useMemo } = React;

let content = {
    para: `<p>A listing page is the public view of a listing. It should informations be designed to display all relevant information about a listing.</p>`,
};

const Example = ({ content }) => {
    const paragraph = useMemo(() => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(content.para, "text/html");
        return <p>{doc.querySelector("p").textContent}</p>;
    }, [content]);

    return (
        <div>
            Here's the paragraph:
            {paragraph}
        </div>
    );
};
const App = () => {
    return <Example content={content} />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I've used [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) there because parsing seems like enough work it's worth memoizing and avoiding repeating.

Comment: What if i want to get content of <ul><li></li></ul>  from content.para?

Comment: @ArsalanAliKhattak - Then it's more complicated, but fundamentally, once you've parsed it to a DOM structure, you can iterate that structure and build the equivalent elements without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (passlisting the elements and attributes you want to allow). It will require a recursive function, but not an especially complicated one.

Comment: @ArsalanAliKhattak - Alternatively, use a well-tested XSS sanitiser and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on its result (on the basis that you've sanitised the content, so it "shouldn't" be dangerous anymore).

Comment: Basically I have a content inside ul and i want to map that content and then render it. through dangrouslySetInnerHTML I can't pass onClick event inside it cuz i have to find keyword in <ul><li> and add a onclick button infront of that keyword which will open a new div.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `String.prototype.slice`

```js
let content = {
  para: `<p>A listing page is the public view of a listing. It should informations be designed to display all relevant information about a listing.</p>`
}

const text = content.para.slice(3, -4)

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new element and pass it your `content.para` value, after use `textContent` on this new element. Like this :

```
const htmlNode = document.createElement('div')
htmlNode.innerHTML = content.para
const sanitizedContent = htmlNode.textContent
```